# Go variant: cyclic or not?

Tags: game-theory, formal-proof

I would like to know if a cycle of moves is possible in the Go variant, Savage Go.  That is, you capture my stones, I capture your stones, you capture my stones... The game never ends.  A position is eventually repeated, completing a cycle.

[Savage Go](https://www.marksteeregames.com/Savage_Go_rules.pdf)

[image: Savage Go]

Cyclicity could be proved simply by finding a cycle.  To disprove cyclicity would require a logical proof.  Either way, it won't be easy.

Don't assume perfect or even reasonably intelligent play.  I need to know if a cycle can possibly happen, even if it takes player cooperation to make it happen.

Comment: No.  Play on a 2x1 grid and White wins on his first move.  Black is annihilated and it's game over.

Comment: The rules are already clear as day.  First of all, Black plays first, just like in Go. As clearly stated in the Object Of The Game section, "Savage Go is a game of annihilation. You win by capturing all of the enemy stones on the board."  Black places a stone and White kills it, thereby winning the game.

Comment: I am taking a break, since I've just constructively shown the existence of closed (Euclidean) knight's tours on any $\{2 \times 2 \times  \cdots \times 2\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^k$ chessboard, as long as $k \geq 7$ is given (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.09639, Theorem 4.1 for the proof). Anyway, in this case, I suspect that the N+1 rule could prevent the existence of any cycle, unless we force a stalemate situation with the only exception of an even number of free squares. This is just a personal note in order to think about it in the next few days.

Comment: Wow, very interesting.  Congratulations on that.  I will study your proof.

Comment: Trying by hand-drawn, I haven't been able to detect any cycle on grids up to 9 vertices. It seems that my first guess could be the correct one... the N+1 rule covers any hole that we can put on the board, reaching the final step where W or B has enough stones to take all the opponents stones, ending the game. I cannot find a way to circumvent this recurring configuration.

Comment: Sometimes, after the board starts to fill up, you can't place all N+1 of your stones.  If a cycle is possible, this is where it would happen.

Comment: Nobody has been able to discover a cycle so far.  But this is kind of proof-by-non-example.  Not a formal proof.

Comment: Once again, this is not an easy problem.  Guys who successfully evaluated other of my games for cyclicity were not able to evaluate this one.

Comment: A proof outline is starting to take shape.  The problem has been narrowed down.  It just needs a spark of genius to crack it.

Comment: Savage Go Proof Outline

RESERVE  Each player has a reserve.  When you capture stones, you put them into your opponent's reserve.  On his turn he plays all of his reserve stones plus one (R+1), or as many as he legally can.  If you're unable to place all the stones from your reserve onto the board, you remove the remaining stones from it. Reserve stones don't carry over. 

TOBARS  Total on board and reserve stones.

PEAK  Highest TOBARS so far.

POSIT  It isn't possible for both players to have less than R+1 placements available on two consecutive turns.

Comment: Case 1:  Both players can consistently play R+1 stones.  TOBARS increases by one every turn.  TOBARS can't reach twice the number of board points before the board fills up and the game ends.

Case 2:  A player can only play R stones.  This must have been immediately preceded by the opponent playing R(previous)+1 stones.  So TOBARS will have increased by 1.  If this pattern continues, the board will fill and the game will end.

Comment: Case 3:  A player can only play R-1 stones.  This must have been immediately preceded by the opponent playing R(previous)+1 stones.  If this pattern continues, TOBARS will alternate between PEAK and PEAK-2, a steady state.  The player on defense will eventually be reduced to zero and lose.

In order for the defensive player to break this pattern, he will have to play R+1 stones immediately following the opponent having played R(previous)+1 stones, increasing PEAK by one. PEAK can't increase without limit.  The game will end before it reaches the number of points on the board.

Comment: There's an active discussion about it in the Savage Go channel here: https://discord.gg/feCAeKxyxD

Comment: The posit is central. It has to be proved.